# QGIS does not open image on Mac

Tags: qgis, qgis-2, mac, osx

I have tried various ways of making an action open on image on my Mac but no image shows up when the point is clicked. The best I got was when I made the field with the file path a "Photo" type. If I open the Attribute table, I can see a little thumbnail of the image. But I want to open the actual image in Preview.

I tried making the field type a "File Name" and assigning an "Open" action. This resulted in absolutely nothing happening when the point was clicked. I also tried making the field type a "Text Edit" and making the Action Type "Mac" and the Action `open [%File Name%]`. Again nothing happened. I checked on "Capture Output" and when I click a point, a box opens that says: 
`Starting open '[%File Name%]'...`

`Done`
... but alas nothing opens. I tested the command in terminal and it opens the image.

I thought maybe it had to do with the absolute file path since the images are on an external hard drive at `/Volumes/external-drive/images/2018_10_24.jpg`. So I copied one to my current folder and changed the command to another column that just lists the individual file without the full path. Still nothing. I even unplugged the external hard drive to see if it gave an error when I ran the above action... same dialogue box with no image opening.

The tutorials on this seem so easy and straight forward, what am I missing here? Is there a permission I need to set on QGIS to let it run shell commands or something?

Answer (score 2):

And, of course, the devil is in the details. Here is the correct open command, due to the fact that my column label has a space in it:

`open [%"File Name"%]`

It had to have *double* quotes.